# Custom HTTPHeader RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers, resttemplate

Where to check if the below headers were added? I checked against firefox and it does not show up. Below code was taken from http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-send-an-http-header-with-every-request-with-spring-resttemplate

```
private HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("X-User-Agent", "test");
    return headers;
}

@RequestMapping("/testClient")
public void test() {

     logger.info("calling ws");
     HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders();
     HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
     ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8081/test", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Boolean.class);
     if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
         logger.info("getbody -" + response.getBody());
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by checking against Firefox? This is making a request out to another service, and you want to pass a request header along, correct?

Comment: I want to see if the request made has the new headers i added. so I called the http://localhost:8083/tesClient and checked the menu-webdeveloper-network tab in firefox. I did not see the new headers I added. It shows some standard headers not the ones I added. Let me know if there is an alternate way to check the newly added headers?

Comment: And why should it should those headers? You are adding them server side for a new request that is going to a different URL. So obviously those will not show up in firefox.

Comment: i have both web service and client running on diff ports. I am using Springboot with embedded tomcat.Where can we trace these newly added headers?